# Flutter & Image Cache : How to build your own cached network image flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, image-caching

I want to implement image cache but I don't want to use the third-party library like `cached_network_image`.
How do I build your own cached network image flutter?

Please take the network image below and use it as an example?

Image Link: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/54469196/100622834-b026a180-3364-11eb-9c35-0582686397d7.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement cached image without using [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) you have to use the plugin which is used by [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) to work i.e [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)
. You can see how the plugin is used in cached_network_image by seeing the code from its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/tree/develop/lib) and accordingly implement in your app.

Hope this will help you! If you still face any problem please inform in comments.

Comment: Yeah, I checked it. But it's a lot to look. I would appreciate if you can pin point the part I might need to take a look

Comment: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/tree/develop/lib/src check here... As to use In your app you will need both widget and backend so widget file will be same but in sec folder choose file according to your need. If you found this helpful then please mark the answer correct and upvote.